# Cakephp Contain Associations not working from alternative controllers

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, model, cakephp-2.3

I have my model associations set up correctly and data is being bought back the way I want it to when I call the `find` method from the corresponding controller. However when I load in the model from another controller and call `model->find` it only returns model data and not its associated data.

I have tried a few things to resolve this including `$this->Model->Behaviors->load('Containable')` but still no luck.

Comment: Formatted code, improved grammar/spelling: you may find including more code (but trying to keep it concise) may help potential answerers better understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Model->find('all' , array('recursive' => -1));
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference neither

Comment: you want just find data model without associated model, the recursive=>-1 do that if its -1 the find method retrieve just the data without the associated model. however i don't think i had understand your question good :)

Comment: Yea i think you miss understood - i want to return all associated data

Comment: This also made no difference. It's the containable doesn't seen to be working when you use loaded models but works fine for it's corresponding  models.

Comment: for example 

Works fine
class User extends AppModel { assosiations... }
class UsersController extends AppController { find.... }

Comment: Doesnt Work
class User extends AppModel { assosiations... }
class RandomController extends AppController { find.... }

Comment: can you post your code , what's RandomController ??

Answer (score 0):

I thankfully found the issue as embarrassing as it was. When i was loading my model i was not prefixing it with the plugin name.

So yea right... if you want to assure your Containable associations will be inherited when you load in your model from an alternative source (non-corresponding controller, shell class) you have to ensure you prefix the model name with it's plugin name if applicable of course.